# Riotexception: No dataset writer for RDF/XML/pretty

Tags: java, xml, exception, bigdata, jena

I'm trying to write a jena Dataset to OutputStream. I want it to be serialized as RDF/XML.

Using jena's RDFDataMgr.write method but it throws an exception:

```
Dataset ds=RDFDataMgr.loadDataset("newFile.jsonld") ;
RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, ds, RDFFormat.RDFXML) ;
```

```
org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: No dataset writer for RDF/XML/pretty
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.createDatasetWriter$(RDFDataMgr.java:1312)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.write$(RDFDataMgr.java:1330)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.write(RDFDataMgr.java:1205)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.write(RDFDataMgr.java:1151)
    at com.ontologycentral.ldspider.http.LookupThread.run(LookupThread.java:166)
```

Can any one throw some light on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can't write a dataset using RDF/XML: RDF/XML can write graphs, not datasets which many contain many graphs.

Either

- Limit yourself to writing an individual graph, for example `RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, ds.getDefaultModel(), RDFFormat.RDFXML) ;` or `ds.getNamedModel(...model name...)`.

or

- Use a format that *can* write datasets like `RDFFormat.TRIG` or `RDFFormat.NQUADS`.

The former will give you RDF/XML, but at the potential cost of losing information. The latter will preserve the original data.